# Why isn't this javascript function added to my attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, electron

I'm making an app with electron, i've implemented a function that adds tabs to this app and they get added properly.

Problem is, when i add them directly in my html file with their class and attributes they work, but when i add them via javascript it all collapses when i try to add the onclick attribute directly from this same function in javascript, it shows up as a tab as expected but doesn't execute the code that hides and shows the content of the tabs like the manually added ones.

i'm pretty sure the function adds everything it needs to execute properly but please prove me wrong.

Here's the function that adds the tab, it should call openTab() onclick, it works when added manually:

```
function addTab() {
  const button = document.createElement("button");

  button.className = "tab-link";
  button.innerHTML = "New Tab";
  button.onclick = "openTab(event,'test')"

  document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0].appendChild(button);

}
```

This is the function i'm using that hides and shows content if it might help:

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-link");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: `button.onclick = "openTab(event,'test')"` this line poses the problem. In html you can write that, but not in js. In js you need to write it as a real function assignment. `button.onclick = event => openTab(event,'test')`

Comment: DO NOT treat the HTML `onclick="doThings(event)"` syntax as the sane version of doing things properly. That syntax is more like a clumsy attempt to patch a markup language with scripting ability. In HTML there’s no concept of function, so they must be expressed in the form of string. But in reality that’s assigning a function to the the `.onclick` property of some HTML element in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The value passed to `onclick`'s setter should be a *function*, not a string. You also need to *call* `openTab` with the event and `'test'` when the click listener is invoked, not invoke the click listener immediately. Do:

```
button.onclick = e => openTab(e, 'test');
```

Also, better to use `classList` than to mess with the `className` string:

```
const active = document.querySelector('.tab-link.active');
if (active) {
  active.classList.remove('active');
}
evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
```

Also, rather than iterating through the `tabcontent` elements, you might consider adding a class with a `display: block` CSS rule instead - that way you can use `querySelector` to select the one open tab (if any) and remove the class, just like what's being done above.

Since you're using Electron, feel free to use ES6+ syntax everywhere - no need to use `var`.